# Perl to escape whitespace in a path

Tags: perl, whitespace

I have a path in a string with whitespace.

For example: `$file="/application/Revenue Setting/settings.xml"`

I know I need to put a "\" in front of the whitespace to make it work.  I just cannot get the regex to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to put a backslash in front of a space in order for Perl to see it as a space.  What you are doing is assigning a string value to the scalar `$file`, and you are not doing anything with regular expressions at all.  Can you show us the actual code you're having a problem with and describe the problem?

Comment: What are you doing with `$file` that you think needs the spaces escaping? If you just want to open it for reading then `open my $fh, '<', $file` will work fine as it is

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are building a shell command. If so, you need to escape far more than just spaces.

If you can't avoid the shell, you should be using [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::ShellQuote)'s `shell_quote`.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote("xml-pretty", $xml_qfn);
my $pretty_xml = `$cmd`;
```